# How can I import an image file into a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, image-processing, ssis

What is the best practice to insert an image from disk to the database using SSIS and BIDS 2008?

I have tried so far using an Script Component as Source and adding it an output column of type `DT_IMAGE`. However, I try to assign a value to this column, BIDS complaints it's read-only.
It seems that I'll have to write ADO.NET code to do the INSERT myself. Is there any other choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [Import Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141262%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which supports binary data. There is an example of using it with binary files [here](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2008/02/02/importing-files-using-ssis/).

Comment: Thanks, your solution is very elegant! 
I had already solved it using a foreach enumerator and an ExecuteSql with command "INSERT INTO myTable(Document) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '{0}', SINGLE_BLOB) as imagefile", replacing the {0} with the path provided by the foreach enumerator. I'll switch to ImportColumn right now.